# Python error 'str' object has no attribute 'randrange'

Tags: python, python-2.7

What causes this error in python?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/coding/python/python programming for absolute beginners/chapter 4/
  The Jumble Game.py", line 9, in <module>
    p=random.randrange(len(word))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'randrange'
```

Code:

```
import random
print"\t\t\tThe Jumble Game"
print"In this program you will be given a jumble word and you have to guess that word"
set=("book","parrot","rabbit")
word=random.choice(set)
random=""
jumble=""
while(word):
    p=random.randrange(len(word))
    random=random+word[position]
    word=word[:position]+word[(position+1):]
print("The jumble word is",random)
```

Comment: you overshadow random module with empty string variable.

Comment: @EricLeschinski: no, the name is just *rebound* in the same scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reused the name `random`:

```
random=""
```

From there on out, the name `random` references a string object, not the module. Rename that variable to not shadow the module you imported.

To shuffle up a word, it'll be easier to use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) instead:

```
word = random.choice(set)
letters = list(word)
random.shuffle(letters)
jumbled_word = ''.join(letters)
print "The jumble word is", jumbled_word
```

Comment: thanks #Martijn Pieters

Answer (score 0):

**How to reproduce this error in python interpreter:**

```
>>> import random
>>> type(random)
<type 'module'>
>>> random.randrange(2)
1
>>> random.randrange(2)
0
>>> random = ""
>>> type(random)
<type 'str'>

>>> random.randrange(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'randrange'
```

You poisoned the well by redefining the random module to be of type string.  Then you invoked a method randrange on a string.  And it's telling you the string object does not have it.